# Can we inject spring bean and a mocked version of the same at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing

I have SpringBootTest class at which i am using `TokenGenerator` class to generate real tokens

```
@Autowired
private TokenGenerator tokenGenerator;
```

Now i need to mock one method in that `TokenGenerator`

can i define a new mocked version of the same bean like

```
@MockBean
private TokenGenerator mockedTokenGenerator;
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What problem do you have? You can use [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) to create partial mocks if you don't want the whole object to be a mock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can also use [@SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) to create partial mocks if you don't want to mock the whole object.